# Lua: how to check whether a process is running

Tags: process, lua

I would like to start a process from Lua and monitor whether the process is still running.

[EDIT]
I know starting can be achieved by os:execute, but this is blocking. I would like to find a way to start a process non-blocking and monitor whether it still runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Lua library provides functions to (asynchronously) start and monitor processes.

[http://stevedonovan.github.io/winapi/](http://stevedonovan.github.io/winapi/api.html#Class_Process)

Comment: uf, You should have mentioned that You need it specifically for Windows :)

Answer (score 0):

One of the blunt ways would be just using [io.popen()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-io.popen) and monitoring it's output or processes them self using some other Linux tool like [ps](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/ps1.html).

Another way would be using some Lua POSIX bindings like [POSIX.signal](https://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/modules/posix.signal.html) and [POSIX.unistd#fork()](https://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/modules/posix.unistd.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using luajit you can use the foreign function interface to directly call the OS api functions. e.g. for Linux or similar.

```
local ffi = require("ffi")
local C = ffi.C
ffi.cdef[[
  int fork(void);
  int execlp(const char* file, const char *arg, ...);
  int waitpid(int pid, int *status, int options);
  void _exit(int status);
  unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);
]]

local pid = C.fork()

if pid > 0 then -- parent
  print("Waiting for child process:");
  local status = ffi.new('int[1]')
  local WNOHANG = 1
  local done = false
  while not done do
    local id = C.waitpid(-1, status, WNOHANG)
    if id == pid then
      done = true
    elseif pid < 0 then
      print("error occurred")
      os.exit(-1)
    else
      print("status=",status[0])
      C.sleep(1)
      -- do other stuff. We aren't waiting
    end
  end
  print("Child exited with status=", status[0])
elseif pid == 0 then -- child
  print("Starting child")
  C.execlp('sleep', 'sleep', '5')
  C._exit(-1)   -- exec never returns
elseif pid < 0 then -- failure
  print("failed to fork")
end
```

You'll see that with the WNOHANG = 1 you can still get a result back to see if the child has exited but then carry on to do other things.

Answer (score -3):

Coroutines in Lua allow you to do what you need (since Lua 5.0):

```
local function Body()
    print( "First resume" )

    coroutine.yield()

    print( "Second resume" )

    coroutine.yield()

    print( "Final resume" )
end

local co = coroutine.create( Body )

print( type( co ) )  -- prints "thread"

coroutine.resume( co )  -- prints "First resume"

print( "After first yield" )

coroutine.resume( co )  -- prints "Second resume"

print( "After second yield" )

coroutine.resume( co )  -- prints "Final resume"

print( coroutine.status( co ) ) -- "suspended", "dead"
```